# ABP.IO Blazor UI Template extremely slow

Tags: abp

I am using the ABP.IO template for the first time. I have used the AspNetZero template for many years.

I downloaded the Blazor UI template today. I followed the Get Started docs and how to run the application steps from the ABP IO docs.

I have setup the **.IdentityServer, .HttpApi.Host and the .Web projects** as **Startup projects** in my solution respectively.

The API and Identity projects open fairly quickly. However the **WEB project** is taking minutes and I mean like **5 to 15 minutes to load each page/view**. I am using a local SQL server express as my DB.

Can someone tell me what I should check and/or what could be the cause of my slowness?

These messages occasionally show up in the console.
[image]

I **created** the solution using the **below steps**.

- Ran command: abp new EXLNT.ContractOps -u blazor --separate-identity-server
- Command log:
- [09:01:47 INF] ABP CLI (https://abp.io)
- [09:01:48 INF] Version 4.0.0 (Stable)
- [09:01:51 INF] Creating your project...
- [09:01:51 INF] Project name: EXLNT.ContractOps
- [09:01:51 INF] UI Framework: Blazor
- [09:01:51 INF] Create Solution Folder: no
- [09:01:51 INF] Output folder: c:\Development\DOTNET\ABP.IO
- [09:01:54 INF] Downloading template: app, version: 4.0.0
- [09:02:00 INF] Check out the documents at https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Startup-Templates/Application
  [09:02:03 INF] 'EXLNT.ContractOps' has been successfully created to 'c:\Development\DOTNET\ABP.IO'
- Then I ran the DBMigrator console app to create the DB
- Then I setup three projects (**.IdentityServer, .HttpApi.Host and .Web projects**) as startup projects in the solution

When I run the application everything is running extremely slowly, on the web app. The home page takes like 10+ minutes to even appear/render. Then when I click on login or any nav menu item it take well over 15+ minutes.

A couple things I changed from the very first attempt:

- I switched from my docker container SQL Server to local non-docker SQL Server
- I turned off my VPN so as to remove that as some obstacle to some client library not being able to load.

Comment: I don't think the problem is caused by abp blazor ui template. So please share the code and steps.

Comment: I have not made any code changes. All I have done is changed the connection string to my local SQL server. I  created template using abp cli.

Comment: With this command I downloaded a new template "abp new MyProject -u blazor --separate-identity-server" but I cannot repeat the problem. Can you provide a project to reproduce the problem?

Comment: check you have followed these steps:  https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-Setup-Environment?UI=Blazor&DB=EF&Tiered=No

Comment: I dont know that sharing my code will do anything. I followed all of the docs, getting started and running the app docs. I followed each one step by step. And all I have done thus far is update the connection string to my local SQL Server. Sometimes the app does work and even when it does it literally takes minutes for each button click or any event.

Comment: @berkansasmaz I just setup a brand new solution using the exact command you used. Once again, I have NOT changed any code. I simply updated the connection string with my SQL server instance name. I then ran DBMigrator to get the DB created. Then I started all three required projects. Its now been about 5+ minutes and neither of the three projects are working or running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I **solved** my issue!

I am working on a brand new laptop. So I was busy installing so many of the required development tools and libraries that **I forgot to install REDIS**. I went back to the ABP.IO Getting started docs and saw the note about REDIS! My bad!

Comment: Hi! Could you elaborate on that? I have the same issue, I never used Redis and I don't know how should I set it up on Windows 10 and make my ABP Blazor app benefit from it.

Comment: I used the following tutorial to set it up and it works well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nFwPTHOMIY